# How Tighten Kitchen Faucet?

Tags: kitchens, faucet

I have a kitchen faucet that is a Moen, a replacement for the old one I tossed about a year ago.  Since then, the Moen isn't secured tightly, and it's bothered me enough to try to fix it.

I just don't know how to tighten it.  Well, what tool to use.  I certainly don't have it.

Thank you for your input.

Cheers

**Update**:  It's a very large nut and won't take a normal basin wrench.  It's evident in the image, but people don't look at the image.

[image]

Comment: [try this](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/14828/are-either-of-these-tools-suitable-for-tightening-the-pipe-union-nut-underneath)

Comment: Or this? [How can I prevent my faucet from spinning?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/231607/35141)

Comment: Or this? [What tool to tighten nut on kitchen faucet?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/158266/what-tool-to-tighten-nut-on-kitchen-faucet)

Comment: Or this? [Tightening a Moen Faucet Lock Nut](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/80938/tightening-a-moen-faucet-lock-nut)

Comment: @FreeMan I own that basin wrench.  This nut is probably twice the size.

Comment: Then get a bigger basin wrench. Not every nut on my car is a 10mm, so I own a set of sockets in different sizes. (and a dozen 10mm because they always disappear)

Comment: @FreeMan They don't make basin wrenches big enough for this.  And I don't want to spend $300 on individual tools to tighten one nut.  I'm going to test some vice grips.

Comment: Then it might have been useful to specify the nut size in the question and indicate that you'd already tried a basin wrench and that it wouldn't fit. Good communication _is_ difficult, but it's worth it to make the effort to be clear so as to not waste people's time hunting down half a dozen example that seem to answer your question when those have, apparently, already been tried but didn't work.

Comment: @FreeMan You mean by posting an image of the nut?  Half a dozen?  I don't know the nut size as I can barely reach the thing.  I thought posting a picture of this large slip nut would suffice, but you want me to take apart the whole thing to measure the nut to ask what tool I should use.

Comment: If you know the model of the faucet, you could probably get the nut size from the installation instructions. Oh, and sorry, only 4 answers (to the question you asked) were found _and linked_, not half a dozen.

Comment: the clear plastic tube should be part way inside the metal tube

Answer (score 1):

I feel your pain.  Been there where there is almost no room to grab the nut and be able to turn.  The good news is they usually do turn easily and 1/4 to 1/2 turn snugs them up.

Now...How?   I had to make a "wrench" out of aluminum plate. Cut it kind of like a big "U" with the opening the size of the nut.  Attached that to a piece of PVC pipe, ( anything as a handle can be used)  and was able to get that nut tight.
Good Luck.

Comment: Thanks for that info.  I emailed the manufacturer and they said a basin wrench, but the one I bought (for this) is the standard size and too small.  The large ones are rare and of single use pretty much.  So I'm going to try some vice grip solutions.  Cheers